# Invalid Google markup rel=publisher

Tags: web-development, google-search-console, validation

Why is Google publisher HTML tag invalid according to W3C specification? Is there any way to correct this example:

```
<a href="http://plus.google.com/109469573972649651137?prsrc=3" rel="publisher" class="c3">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure with your question whether you mean that the Google `rel=publisher` doesn't work for your site, or that it works but w3 is saying its invalid.

If it's not working with Google you can use the rich snippets testing tool here:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

If its working with Google but w3 is showing it as invalid, i wouldn't say that's that much of a problem as the code is only going to be used by Google so as long as they can read it. Also, I think it's important to note that search engines are very good at interpreting HTML even bad or invalid HTML.  So it not being 100% valid isn't something I'd be too concerned about especially if it's just this one link.

Comment: i got a hack around it its simple just as in verification of author here if an example         <a href="https://plus.google.com/109469573972649651137?rel=publisher"></a> happy coding

Answer (score 1):

i got a hack around it its simple just as in verification of author here if an example             `<a href="https://plus.google.com/109469573972649651137?rel=publisher">` happy coding

Answer (score 0):

W3C valiation accepts the following markup (note the use of `'` instead of `"`):

```html
<link href='https://plus.google.com/u/0/000000000000000' rel='publisher'>
```